# Check if the residence's connection has internet access

Tags: bash, networking, testing

I'd like to be able to test if I have access to the internet. My computer is connected to the residence internet connection.
I thought of using `ping` like this:

```
ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo ok || echo error
```

But this does not work!

As I said the connection is provided by a residence(which is actually just forwarding the university connection). To have access to the internet you *must* open a web browser where you are requested user name and password and only then the internet access is granted.(I really have no clue about networks configurations etc. and anyway I do not have any access to how it is setup, so I can't provide more information on this side)

The above code prints "ok" even when I do not actually have access to the internet. Even testing with `www.google.com` fails. I believe this is because it is being redirected to the login page and it "thinks" to get back the packets correctly.

How can I reliably check if I have access to the internet?

### Some context

I'd like to connect to the computer in my room via `ssh` when I go home during weekends. The connection sometimes fails so I'd like to create a script that every once in a while checks for the connection and eventually starts a web browser and sends keystrokes using `xdotool` to login.
If you know a better way to reopen the connection to allow `ssh` remote access than, please, write it too.

**Update:**

Some sample output of `nslookup`:

```
$ nslookup unix.stackexchange.com
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   unix.stackexchange.com
Address: 69.59.197.21
```

The result is exactly the same both with internet access and without it.
(I've also tried to log off and relog, and connect and disconnect multiple times).

Also, I'd like to add that is not the `ssh` connection closing.
For some time I'm able to create the connection, do things and log out. After some hours trying to do `ssh the-IP` gives a timeout error(I actually registered a no-ip account since the IP is dynamic so I'm doing `ssh mydomain.no-ip.org`).

Comment: Try querying the DNS servers (if it is Internet based): `nslookup unix.stackexchange.com`. If you get a full answer, then you have internet connection. Mind you, quite a few firewalls only block TCP traffic and forget all about UDP. In that case DNS-queries are resolved properly while you will not be able to download any content from a webserver.

Comment: @jippie I tried now but it does not seem to work, it returns the same output when having internet access and when not having it. Maybe the DNS lookup is cached? If so how to clear the cache?

Comment: On a side note, during this weekend I tested that `ssh` works from home, but after some hours the connection was lost.

Comment: Totally depends on what DNS server you're querying. That is in the answer being returned (Server: ...). If it is a public IP, then you have internet connection, if it is a private IP address then you just won't know (unless you can think of a hostname that nobody else thought of for the past 24hrs or so.

Comment: SSH can time out on its own when the SSH tunnel is idle. There can be many reasons that causes this behaviour (including a shared firewall).

Comment: @jippie I've added some more information at the bottom of the question. As I say there, it's definitely not `ssh` dropping the connection. I'm wondering if it could be a dynamic IP issue. Maybe the computer's IP get reassigned and thus `ssh` connections drop(but I thought IP would not change if the computer does not at least reboot...)

Comment: DHCP can perfectly well assign an alternative IP address while the computer is running, it is easy to check (`ifconfig` or in `/var/log/messages`).

Comment: Uhm. So I should test `ifconfig`'s output and when the IP changes I should kill the browser and restart it?

Comment: What about the simple answer of: Complain to the university until they fix the problem?

Comment: Browser should be fine, SSH may drop (depends).

Comment: You are in a VM? In other words, why do you get a localhost addres for the DNS server? (Server:         127.0.1.1)

Comment: No, I'm not on a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what I required seems to download a random webpage and see if the contents match the login page or not.

For example doing:

```
$ wget www.google.com
```

Will download the html content of google's page if I have internet access, while it would just contain something like:

```
<!--
**
**  ZEROSHELL Captive Portal Login Page  
**
**          (Native Interface)
**
-->

<html>
<head>
<title>Web Login</title>
    ...
</html>
```

If it's being redirected to the login page.
It seems to work well to detect what I want, even though I hoped to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You made a fatal mistake in your command.

```
ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null && echo ok || echo error
```

The command `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` returns your default gateway. As a result, `ping`, instead of checking Google, checks the router you are connected to. The router will send back a packet, which makes the whole command true. That's why it always returns "ok". It does not check internet connectivity at all. But, look at the bright side. It checks if you are connected to LAN.

Anyways, you may want to use `ping -q -w 1 -c 1 google.com > /dev/null && echo ok || echo error` instead of using `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3`.

Comment: Did I just bump an old thread? *sudden realization*

Comment: Yes, although I still find your answer useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a program like [AutoWifi](http://www.manatlan.com/page/autowifi).

Comment: Yes, but I have to connect through an Ethernet cable and not wifi.

Answer (score 0):

How about IF?

```
if [[ $(ping -c1 -w1 google.com) ]]
then 
    echo "All good in the hood"
else
    echo "Where are my interwebs?"
fi
```

or as one line

```
if [[ $(ping -c1 -w1 google.com) ]]; then  echo "All good in the hood"; else; echo "Where are my interwebs?"; fi
```

Comment: This does not work. It will always return "true" even when I don't actually have internet access.